# Extract Map from config.properties

Tags: java, properties-file

I am trying to get map from my properties file, which goes as below:

```
Mapping = { "NAME-1":"AAA,aa,bb" , "NAME-2":"BBB,bb,cc" }
```

In My class file, I am doing this

```
@Value("${Mapping}")
private String mapping;

@Bean
public Map<String,String> getMapping() {
    log.debug("inside mapping");
    Map<String,String> mapping = new HashMap<String,String>();
    return mapping;
}
```

Which is not working, please help.

Comment: Pardon me but your question is not clear. Do you have a file named `config.properties`? Are you trying to create a `java.util.Map` from the contents of that file?

Comment: @Abra...YES Thats correct

Comment: Does this help? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html

Comment: Thanks @Abra...It cleared my perspective

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
    @Value("#{${Mapping}}")
    private Map<String,String> mapping;

    @Bean
    public Map<String,String> getMapping() {
        return mapping;
    }
```

This works in a minimal project.